# Finding where a handle is open to

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, hook

I'm messing around with handles / hooks, and have a question. Right now, I have a DLL that I inject into the process that I'm playing with. The DLL hooks the CloseHandle() function. When CloseHandle is called, I do the following:

```
int WINAPI DetourCloseHandle(HANDLE hObject)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("CLOSE HADNLE");
    char name[MAX_PATH];
    GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hObject, name, MAX_PATH, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED);
    OutputDebugStringA(name);

    return oCloseHandle(hObject);
}
```

My goal in this is to figure out where the handle is open to, and if the handle is open to a certain process, then use the handle to read that processes memory. What gets printed out when CloseHandle is called is usually paths to random files that the application reads, but I also noticed random ASCII characters being printed at times, as the "Name" of where the handle is opened to. [This can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugLoA.png)

Sometimes I also notice paths to certain .exe files. This is not unusual, as the application that I'm injecting into does read / look at binary files. My question is, when I see the "name" returned from GetFinalPathNameByHandle as the path to an exe file, how do I know if the handle is opened to the binary file itself, or if the handle file is opened to the actual running process with that name.

I would also like some insight as to what the ASCII characters that are being printed are. Thanks!

Comment: Since you don't bother to check whether the function call succeeded, the most likely explanation is that it failed (perhaps because the handle in question isn't a file handle) and you're printing whatever random data happened to be sitting in the buffer.

Comment: are you using c or c++

Answer (score 1):

For the random data print you pasted, it likely was because it is just uninitialized garbage in name array, you should always check `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`'s return value before do something with name:

```
DWORD ret = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hObject, name, MAX_PATH, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED);
if (ret) {
    OutputDebugStringA(name);
} else {
    OutputDebugStringA("GetFinalPathNameByHandle");
    // check GetLastError()
}
```

Also, note that `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` thake the string as `TCHAR` strings, and you are print it via `OutputDebugStringA`. So I would suggest either use the ANSI version `GetFinalPathNameByHandleA`, or use `TCHAR name[MAX_PATH];` and print with `OutputDebugString` instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. How do I know if a handle is opened to the process or the actually .exe file though ?

Comment: @user3749382 It's opened to the process, it means the process opened the .exe file.

Comment: I don't think you understand. What if the application is just reading the actual .exe file off the disk? I need a handle opened to the running process itself, that lets me read the running memory of the process, not the .exe file. It's like a handle opened using CreateFile() vs a handle opened using OpenProcess(). The handle created using CreateFile is opened to the .exe file, and reads the contents of the binary file on the disk, where as the handle opened using OpenProcess using the PID is a handle to the memory of that running process. I need the ladder.

Comment: The handle belongs to the running process that opened the file, not the exec file, it is possible that the exec is not even running as a process, think about the case of linker, for example.

Comment: I don't want to see what owns the handle, I'm trying to figure out what the handle is opened to.